# Binary Classification Task on Very Similar Patterns

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I'm trying to do a binary classification task on a set of sentences which are so similar to each other. My problem is I'm not sure how to deal with this problem with such similarity between samples. Here are some of my questions:

(1). Which classification technique will be more suitable in this case?

(2). Will feature selection help in this case?

(3). Could sequence classification algorithms, based on recurrent neural network (LSTM) be a potential approach to follow?

I'll be glad to see any hint or help regarding to this problem, thank you!

Comment: I'm surprised! Why minus scoring? What is wrong with the question? Maybe I need to consider clustering algorithms rather than classification ones?

Comment: I'm guessing the scoring is because this type of questions isn't appropriate for SO, see the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I suggest you try [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @ncfirth! I changed the topic.

Comment: What is 'so similar"? this question does not make any sense...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse As it was explained above, 'so similar' refers to sentences which represent samples of the dataset.

Comment: I still don't understand the question.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse Let's say I have a dataset which is a matrix of m*n, where m and n represents rows (samples) and columns(features) respectively. The challenging issue that I'm trying to find out is : Samples are so similar to each other .i.e. most of the feature's value for different samples are similar (or close to each other). In other words samples are almost in the same position in the vector space. The question is how to perform a binary classification task while we have such similar samples? I hope I explained it clearly this time :)

Answer (score 0):

(only a potential Answer to 3)
Assuming you only have to classify if they are in a certain category you wouldn't want to use RNN's unless you actually want it to make something new out of it (sequence-to-sequence)

That said it is possible to classify it if you end it with a sequence-flattener and a fully-connected-Layer

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My data samples are sentences (short sentence) and the class label is either 0 or 1. So, actually I'm going to use RNN to build a predictive model rather than a generative model.